eSata 3TB HDD enclosure connecting to laptop
I want to connect an eSata 3TB HDD enclosure to a Lenovo T500 laptop.
USB 2.0 ports on laptop are not working, because there is a 2.2TB limit.
Laptop has an ExpressCard54 slot.

Can I use the enclosure with that Expansion Card ExpressCard 34mm?
3TB HDD was formatted and wrote by desktop PC via eSATA port. Can I reach the data with laptop using the express card?
Thx!


What OS are you using? What did you format the harddrive as?

I think there's a few moving parts here. E-sata is sata, so in theory if the OS supports it, it should work. I think a wrinkle here is Expresscard's old - I think last common around 2010.  It possible the chipset in the expresscard may or may not support it - not cause its expresscard, but cause its an older PCI(e?) sata bridge

@Burgi Originally was the eSATA 3TB drive formatted with Windows 7 PC. Now I will use on Windows 10 laptop.

@JourneymanGeek Original PC is an Intel Core2 Duo Processor E8400. Now laptop is Lenovo T500 Dual Core or Lenovo P50 Xeon E3-1535M v5.
